# difference between c# and asp.net/c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

do i need to be as strong in c# as an asp.net/c# developer as i would as a c# desktop application developer? there seems to be much less c# coding involved when developing asp.net websites than desktop applications. are there certain things in c# that aren't used as often when used in asp.net websites than in desktop software? i was just wondering if there were different ways of approaching learning the language depending on how it will be applied. thanks.

Comment: difference between c# and asp.net/c# - when you see them, you'll shit bricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to know all the basics of the language when working with ASP.Net.

There are, of course, things that you won't need when working in one or another.

e.g.
 When working with ASP.Net, you don't need to know anything about WinForms, and most of the time you won't be working with things like threads.

When working with ASP.Net you'll also have to learn lots of things outside C#, and basically learn the basics of web development.

In my personal experience, one of the things that took me a while to get used to was the stateless model of web development (I worked a lot in desktop applications and this model wasn't very clear at first).

So, yes, you have to be strong at c# to start working with ASP.Net.

As an approach, I recommend you read something about the stateless model, that's a good way to start, in my opinion.

Best regards

Answer (score 4):

> do i need to be as strong in c# as an asp.net/c# developer as i would as a c# desktop application developer?

Yes.

> there seems to be much less c# coding involved when developing asp.net websites than desktop applications

No, not less c#. Just different c#.

Here's the secret: start building your web application and when you run into something you don't know how to do, ask it here.

Answer (score 0):

You're implying a separation where none exists. The only real difference between ASP.Net and WinForms development is the delivery method. The concepts are the same. Development needs, language restrictions, data concepts, everything still derives from the same framework. The only thing that is truly different is how that end product gets to the customer.

Don't get bogged down in the details of the platform. I think you would do well to understand both platforms of delivery because they are different even if most of it happens "under the covers". Understanding the differences between the two delivery platforms is very useful though.

Comment: -1: the concepts are certainly not the same. Web == stateless. Big difference.

Comment: @John - I would categorize that as a mechanism of the delivery method. While the page is being executed in the thread, the state is identical. An important distinction to be sure, but I did mention that difference in my answer. Thanks for the comment. A lot of people seem to mark -1 and not bother to say why they disagree.

Comment: @Joel: you really sound like you don't understand HTTP at all. Are you an ASP.NET developer?

Comment: @John Saunders - actually yes, I am an ASP.Net developer, and I understand http just fine. C# even in ASP.Net involves more than just the delivery across the protocol.

Comment: @John I think Joel's point is that for any application of note, the layer at which you care whether the end-user is coming through via HTTP or WinForms is pretty small. The part of the iceberg that's underwater, so to speak, is mostly agnostic to that.

Comment: @Joel: @Rex: I completely disagree. The stateless nature of HTTP, the fact that the UI operates on a different computer from the server-side code; the multithreaded nature of that code; these are some things that make ASP.NET development very different from desktop development. I think it is amazing that you can minimize these facts.

Comment: @John Saunders - Most of the code I write has nothing to do with any of the topics you've mentioned and can be employed both in WinForms and ASP.Net. I understand the point you're trying to make, I just think it's a very minor part of developing in .Net overall if your goal is to be well-rounded (which is how I interpret the OPs question).

Comment: I imagine if I was rewriting a webpage (say, Google search) as a desktop app, it'd be 90% the same (still need a crawler, parser, database, query engine, etc).  I think the disagreement here is about project scope.  *Most* web pages are still really simple CRUD apps.  So the *average* ASP.NET app might be significantly different from the *average* desktop app.  But for a given non-trivial problem, the solution to that in a desktop app and on a webpage will be mostly the same.

Comment: The upshot of that is that the answer is different depending on whether you're looking to be a developer of average ASP.NET pages, or if you have a program in mind and haven't decided upon a delivery mechanism yet.

Comment: @Joel: use ViewState at all? How about postback? Then you're writing code that depends on the stateless model of HTTP, and which works to hide the statelessness from you.

Comment: @John Saunders - Yes, I have used all of those tools. And they still comprise less than 25% of the total code that I write for ASP.Net applications. You're actually starting to make my point for me clinging to these very few aspects of the language. I'm not sure why an MVP can't make the connection with the point I'm making when other people seem to be. Nor why you'd be arguing so vehemently towards it. Your tone suggests some sort of offense, and I really like your earlier condescending remark about my skill set. Maybe an MVP should feel less threatened by an opinion. EOD.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET does a lot of its magic by creating and compiling classes on the fly and calling methods using reflection or on interfaces. You will understand the framework and what it is doing "behind the scenes" a lot better if you actually understand C# (or VB.NET or the .NET Framework in general)